# scikit learn 0.18.1: 'module' object has no attribute 'neural_network'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Hi I am trying to use MLP

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn as sk

X = [[0., 0.], [1., 1.]]

Y = [[1.1, 1.1], [2.1, 2.1]]

reg = sk.neural_network.MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)
```

I thought neural network is available for 0.18.1 but I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'neural_network'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this kind of import:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
```

And adapt your remaining code for this like:

```
reg = MLPRegressor(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)
```

Consider reading the python doc's on [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).